# Paginate with Angularjs filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have been using Angularjs for a dynamic table , I applied filter and pagination(UI Bootstrap Pagination) ,the filter works fine but i filters data on every page on the paginated pages. the pagination is not updating

```
<tr class="instances" ng-repeat="instance in fail_instances.slice(((currentPage_fail-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage_fail)*itemsPerPage)) | filter:searchText">
```

Pagination:

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems_pass" ng-model="currentPage_pass" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] along with a concise and proper problem description as well as expected behavior

Comment: That pagination uses a different model than the ng-repeat does

Comment: doesn't it have any fix

Comment: fix for what...you haven't explained expected behavior or explained the mismatch between pagination and ng-repeat or updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the dirPagination rather as it is quite flexible and will also update the data pages dynamically based on filteration criteria.

Try this link: -- //plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

check if it is what you require.